# Specific columns using eloquent in a nested eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Is there a way to only **limit the number of columns** that one can select in a **nested eager loading** in Laravel?

Currently, I have 3 models that inter-relate. For instance, let's assume that we have the **Publisher model, Authors model, and books model**.

A publisher has a relationship with the Authors and the Authors have a relation with the book's models.

**The Publisher model has columns like:**

- id
- name
- address
- fax number
- email address

**The author's models contain:**

- id
- name
- address
- email
- published books
- publishers_id

**The books models contain:**

- id
- title
- authors_id
- published_on
- category

If I want to check the books that have been published by a given publication company: This is how I pull the records

```
$published_books::Publisher::with('authors.books')->take(1);
```

With this, I get a response like this:

```
"id" : 1,
"name" : "Longhorn Ke",
"address" : "14th Street",
"fax number" : "null",
"email_address" : "longhorn@mail.com",
"author" :{
 "id" : 4,
 "name" : patel,
 "email" : patelguru@mail.com,
 "published_books" : 12,
 "publishers_id" : 1,
 "books" : {
  "id": 1,
  "title" : "Art of life",
  "authors_id" : 1,
  "published_on" : "2020-07-12 14:22:25",
  "category" : "Life teachings",
 }

}
```

What I want is that when I load a book through the relationship I only want to get the name of the publisher, name of the author and the books details as shown below:

```
"id" : 1,
"name" : "Longhorn Ke",
"author" :{
     "id" : 4,
     "name" : patel,
     "books" : {
         "id": 1,
          "title" : "Art of life",
          "authors_id" : 1,
          "published_on" : "2020-07-12 14:22:25",
          "category" : "Life teachings",
 }

}
```

How can I achieve that using eloquent? At this point, I understand that eloquent allows selection of specific columns on a nester load as shown in this link https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns but how do I do it in all the models to achieve the code result show above

Answer (score 1):

For the top-most model you need `select()`; for the relationships you need `relationship:id,...`:

```
$published_books = Publisher::with(['authors.books', 'authors:id,name'])
    ->select('id', 'name')
    ->take(1);
```